# i have create chrome driver object then i got java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, selenium, testng

i m learning TestNG,so i have created one Base class in that i have create object for chrome browser.

this is my base class

```
public class BaseClass {

    public String url="https://dofdev-services.azurewebsites.net/";
    public String username1="info@gravityconsulting.com.au";
    public String password1="Gravity@123";
    public  WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp() 
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir" +"/Drivers/chromedriver.exe"));
        driver=new ChromeDriver();
    }

    @AfterClass()
    public void tearDown() 
    {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

this is my test case class

```
public class TC_LoginPage_001 extends BaseClass{

      @Test
      public  void loginTestCase()
      {
    driver.get(url);
    LoginPagePOM lp=new LoginPagePOM(driver);
    lp.setUserName(username1);
    lp.setPassword(password1);
    lp.clickSignIn();

    if(driver.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
    {

        Assert.assertTrue(true);
    }else {
        Assert.assertTrue(false);
    }
}
```

this is my another class here i have created the constructor(pom class)

```
 public class LoginPagePOM {

 WebDriver driver;

 public LoginPagePOM(WebDriver driver)
  {
    this.driver=driver;
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
      }
    @FindBy(id="userName")
    WebElement username;

    @FindBy(name ="passwords")
     WebElement password;

    @FindBy(name="btn-sdz-login")
     WebElement click;


    public void setUserName(String usname)
          {
      username.sendKeys(usname);
               }

   public void setPassword(String Pass) 
             {
         password.sendKeys(Pass);
     }

     public void clickSignIn()
       {
       click.click();
       }
               }
```

this is exception stack trace (getting null pointer exception)

[image: exception stack trace]

Comment: can anyone help

Comment: You should show us the exception stack trace

Comment: anybody is there

Comment: use static WebDriver driver.

Comment: didn't solve...........

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your constructor has driver object passed in loginpage. You need to pass the driver to all pageclasses. Also login page didnt extend baseclass. You need to extend as below and also remove the webdriver instantiation in loginpage.

Ex:

```
 public class LoginPagePOM extends BaseClass {
    public LoginPagePOM (WebDriver driver) 
        {
            this.driver=driver;

        }

    public void setUserName(){
     ........
     }

    public void setPassword(){
      ........
     }

}
```

Comment: i have this constructor in another class,code is updated now please check it.

Comment: @divyau You should have this constructor in all pageclasses. Unable to see your latest code still. can you debug once and try. Also,Please provide the exception  stacktrace screenshot.

Comment: check it out sir now

Comment: If the browser window itself is not launching, then you should check whether the chrome driver is available in the path provided. and also check whether the driver location is correct or not. put a System.out.println before chromedriver instance creation and verify this too once. Eg: System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir" +"/Drivers/chromedriver.exe"));

Answer (score 0):

You have a driver in your `BaseClass` and then you are again making a driver in the `LoginPagePOM` class, due to which you are getting NPE.
To solve this problem, you have make the driver `static` and then use that single driver in all the classes where you need it. You dont need to initialise it again.
You can use `public static WebDriver driver;` in your `BaseClass` and then you can use `BaseClass.driver` in all you classes where you need it.

Your `TC_LoginPage_001` would be like:

```
public class TC_LoginPage_001 extends BaseClass{

  @Test
  public  void loginTestCase()
  {
BaseClass.driver.get(url);
LoginPagePOM lp=new LoginPagePOM(driver);
lp.setUserName(username1);
lp.setPassword(password1);
lp.clickSignIn();

if(BaseClass.driver.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
{

    Assert.assertTrue(true);
}else {
    Assert.assertTrue(false);
     }
}
```

And your `LoginPagePOM` would be like:

```
public class LoginPagePOM {

 public LoginPagePOM()
  {
    PageFactory.initElements(BaseClass.driver, this);
  }
@FindBy(id="userName")
WebElement username;

@FindBy(name ="passwords")
 WebElement password;

@FindBy(name="btn-sdz-login")
 WebElement click;


public void setUserName(String usname)
      {
  username.sendKeys(usname);
           }

   public void setPassword(String Pass) 
         {
     password.sendKeys(Pass);
 }

 public void clickSignIn()
   {
   click.click();
   }
       }
```

Comment: but where should i write code for open chrome browser??new ChromeDriver();